# Is it a good practice to access the Actvity's Context in the Presenter class? If no then is there any other better way to do it?

Tags: android, mvp, android-context

I am new to `Android MVP Architecture`. As far as I have researched the `Presenter` should be kept free from any android things like for example: Don't use `getActivity` or `Context` in the Presenters. I have written the following code where a `BasePresenter` is the parent class of all the `Presenter` classes that I will be using.The `BaseView` interface is the parent interface of all View classes and `BaseActivity` class is the parent class of all `Activity` classes. I have more than one activity and it is required to show `Toast` messages in all of my activity. So I have written the following code as follows. I am not very sure whether using the `getactivity` from the presenter class is a good practice or not. If it is not then can anyone suggest any better way to do it?

BasePresenter class

```
public class BasePresenter<V extends BaseView> {
private V mView;
private Context mContext;

public void attachView(V view) {
    mView = view;
     mContext=mView.getActivity();
}

public void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

private Context getContext() {
    return mContext;
}

public void detachView() {
    mView = null;
}

}
```

BaseView class

```
 public interface BaseView {
 AppCompatActivity getActivity();
 }
```

BaseActivity class

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public AppCompatActivity getActivity() {
    return this;
}

}
```

MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements MainView {
 MainPresenter basePresenter;
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    basePresenter = new MainPresenter();
    basePresenter.attachView(this);
}

  // some more codes here

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.about:
                    basePresenter.showToast("About is Clicked");

                    break;
                case R.id.cart:
                    basePresenter.showToast("Cart is Clicked");

                    break;
                case R.id.favs:
                    basePresenter.showToast("Favs is Clicked");

                    break;
                case R.id.home:
                    basePresenter.showToast("Home is Clicked");

                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think you got a complete answer, but I hope looking at this sample repo could help you more to understand MVP methodology's aspects: http://github.com/mmirhoseini/fyber_mobile_offers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not a good idea.  You Presenter (base or otherwise) should not know about Context, Activity, Toast or anything else Android based.

View

1. displays things.
2. handles user input and passes it to the `Presenter`.

Presenter

1. decides what to do with user input.
2. gathers data from the model.
3. tells the `View` what to do.

So for your example of clicking Buttons and showing Toasts you would need a setup something like:

### View Interface

This is how your Presenter will talk to your View.  It will be implemented by the Activity.

```
public interface MainView {

    void showToast(String message);
}
```

### Presenter (Base & Main)

BasePresenter has almost no tasks at all.  Simply there to bind the View interface.  Note the method names in the MainPresenter are ambiguous to things like 'click' to seperate them from the View implementation.

```
public class BasePresenter<V> {

    protected V view;

    public void attachView(V view) {
        this.view = view;
    }
}

public class MainPresenter extends BasePresenter<MainView> {

    public void about() {
        view.showToast("About was clicked");
    }

    public void cart() {
        view.showToast("Cart was clicked");
    }
}
```

### Activity

The Activity implements the View interface.  It's responsible for passing user events to the Presenter and actioning the Presenter commands.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MainView {

    private MainPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        presenter = new MainPresenter();
        presenter.attachView(this);

        Button about = findViewById(R.id.button_about);
        about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                presenter.about();
            }
        });

        Button cart = findViewById(R.id.button_cart);
        cart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                presenter.cart();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

In this setup the Presenter no longer knows anything about Android (has no imports from the framework at all) and you are able to write unit tests for it which can run directly on the JVM without Android dependencies.

Comment: So what will you do if you have to localize those hardcoded Strings in presenter hence you don't have access to the context ?

Comment: hardcoded strings have 2 solutions: either call the showToast() function with the string resource id and then inside the view, use the view context to retrieve the actual string. 
Or the second solution is to use a StringHelper class, that is injected in the Presenter constructer, and in the StringHelper class you can hold reference to the context.

Answer (score 2):

Toast is actually visible on screen. So It should not be in presenter. It should be triggered from the View.

Comment: k..I got it, But is it good to access the getActivity method in the Presenter class?

Comment: You should not call getActivity from presenter. Simply use getContext instead. It is the better practice.